# How can I order the rownames of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am using biological data from an imported CSV file where the gene symbols are put into "column 0" as rownames. I would like to order the rows alphabetically based on gene symbol.

I was thinking of extracting the column 0 rownames to a new column and then ordering but I prefer leaving the dataset how it is. Is there anyway to order the row names instead?

Comment: Try: `x <- x[order(rownames(x)),]`

Comment: Yes, it works - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row_names_test <- data.frame(cbind(genes <- rownames(read.csv("~/row_names_test.csv")),
                                   read.csv("~/row_names_test.csv")))

row_names_test <- row_names_test[order(row_names_test$genes), ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind if I need the data this way later. For now I'm trying to keep the rownames in the original df. :)

Comment: rownames(row_names_test) <- row_names_test$genes
row_names_test <- within(row_names_test, rm("genes"))

Please upvote / accept answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I have but my reputation is quite low so i don't know if it displays